# How to know whether a journal accepts concurrent submission to the journal and arXiv?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, arxiv

I am considering submitting my paper to both a computer science journal and arXiv. No version of the paper has been published in any conference or anything at this point.

- Is this going to be an issue with the journal?
- Should I hold off submitting to arXiv?
- If this is journal dependent, how do I find out about the journal policy?

Comment: a good resource is this: http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php

Comment: You cannot get a good answer to this if you don't specify your field.  In math, it would be shocking at this point if you didn't submit to the arXiv, but for many other fields it's different.

Comment: It mainly depends on the specific journal.

Comment: The field is computer science

Comment: What kind of computer science? Theory tends to follow the same practices as math; other subfields tend behave more like engineers.

Comment: @JeffE System performance - Queueing Theory

Comment: What's the name of the journal? In the end, the answer depends on the concrete journal.

Comment: It's an IEEE journal

Comment: So, judging from the answers here...It "could" be an issue. Interesting.

Comment: My understanding of arXiv was that a publication there was tantamount to a "technical report" at a university.

Comment: @BenWebster "in math it would be shocking if you didn't submit to the arxiv" seems a bit excessive - there are some mathematicians who don't use it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Which I consider shocking.  How is anyone supposed to read their papers?  Dead trees 5 years after they were written?

Comment: @BenWebster Quite some journals also publish online before printing. Furthermore, they might put a preprint on their own homepage and link to it. So just because they don't use arXiv should not mean that they don't publish online. I also heard of situations where a paper was hold back by the author until the journal publication (and hence not put on the arXiv), to allow for more study on the topic, preparation for a conference, etc.

Comment: @Bemte That does not eliminate the potentially very long waiting time from submission to acceptance. I have no idea why anyone would delay putting a completed paper on the arXiv to allow for further study when it has already been submitted. It is not like that further study could make it into the paper anyway.

Comment: @Bemte The online journal publishing is better than nothing, I suppose, but  what is the point of writing a paper if you don't want people to read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is field dependent, in particular some fields in the humanities tend to consider "already published" what appeared even on a web page. Also, Glam magazines such as Nature and Science want to be able to keep the papers secret until they release them, possibly with communication toward the press. In mathematics, the most theoretical parts of computer science, and some of physics you can definitely put a preprint on the arXiv before submitting to a journal (there might be journals who don't enable this, but they would be a small minority). There is [an excellent resource](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/index.php) to determine the policy of a journal or publisher.

All of this could be gathered from previous comments. Now, the reason why I write this answer is to stress that for Elsevier, the default policy is that you can put your preprint on the arXiv and later update it according to referee's comment ("postprint" version), but you do not have the right to put the postprint on the arXiv between acceptance and 12 months after publication if the preprint was not there before. To avoid trouble you should thus put your preprint on the arXiv *before acceptance* (before submission being the easiest way).

Comment: Well, some Elsevier journals are pretty "glam" (per ¶1 of this answer).  OP, or OP's university, may end up having to pay for Open Access with the journal.  It doesn't hurt to ask the editorial staff!  **A quick email or phone call could save OP considerable trouble in the end.**

Answer (score -2):

My understanding is that it won't be an issue. The latter is mostly dependent on the aspects relative to the legal nature of the copyright (the contract between you - the author - and the publisher - the journal) and the pair-review process. My understanding is that what you publish in ArXiv is a **raw manuscript** which is the "raw-material" that goes into the pair-review process. The pair reviewed article (**pre-print**) has suffered many "transformations" based on the the reviewing-editors' requests. The copyright you're required to sign, regulates the **pre-print** and not the **raw-manuscript**. Therefore, putting your raw-manuscript on ArXiv shouldn't be an issue as long as the **raw-material** and the **pre-print** are not identical. If the latter is false, the reviewers would have not suggested **any** changes (not even cosmetic changes - rephrasing some fragment, for example) to the article, which, in my experience, is quite rare.

Comment: That's not the main point here. The main issue is that the journal's editors could refuse the manuscript because the result has already appeared online, so it's no longer "unpublished". It's well within their rights to do so, since publishing a paper or not is their own decision and they are free to set criteria and conditions. In some fields journals routinely do that, in some they don't (and doing it would be considered outrageous).